# use string html text to html

Tags: php, html

The question is this, i have some text that i bring from the DB. 
The info is recorded as HTML. 
When i bring that info, it comes as `"<b>hello world</b>"` i mean, it comes all the html as string, and i want to use that string as html. I think there is a function in php for this, but i dont find.

example:
i have `"<b>hello world</b>"` and need to be **hello world**

Comment: Did you look at your source code in the browser?

Comment: Check content-type. Try `header('Content-type: text/html');` in start of output.

Comment: the browser source code shows: "&lt;td class=&quot;d&quot; style=&quot;font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; padding: 0pt; margin: 0pt;&quot;&gt; ", i have to convert the &lt to < and all those special chars

Comment: Where do you put it in the document?

Comment: when you say _When I bring that info, it comes as "<b>hello world</b>"_, what are you using to "bring in that info"? Sure, you could do a simple preg_replace() to kill the bold tags, but lets try to get to the ROOT of the problem... Please give us some code to work with here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the functions

- [htmlentitites()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) (to make **Hello** => `<b>Hello</b>`) and
- [html_entity_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) (to make `<b>Hello</b>` => **Hello**)

Guess that should solve your problem ;)

As from the PHP Manual:

```
<?php 
  $orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";
  $a = htmlentities($orig);
  $b = html_entity_decode($a);
  echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now
  echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
?>
```

Comment: i want the opposite of htmlentities, but the unhtmlentities shows nothing

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($var);
```

I think you use `htmlspecialchar()` when you insert to database

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing an

```
<?php echo "<b>Hello World</b>" ?>
```

in your php page, it will be interpreted as html. So there is no problem ;)

Comment: you should accept correct/acceptable answers when you ask a question